# Reloading configuration file in VsVim?

Tags: visual-studio, vim, vsvim

Is there any way for reloading configuration file (_vsvimrc) for VsVim inside Visual Studio, WITHOUT restarting whole IDE ?

```
:source C:\path\to\_vsvimrc
```

returns

> Parse Error

**UPDATE 2014-05-12**

Configuration actually reloaded properly, beside some line that was wrong.
In my _vsvimrc I also bind my basic _vimrc file used also in Vim. This was probably the problem. I didn't debug it. I just live with it :).

My config file can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/aburok/mysettings).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Late reply, but if it returns Parse Error, then that sounds like a problem in your _vsvimrc.

I just tried it to be sure, and it definitely works with my minimal _vsvimrc, so I introduced an error and got a Parse Error.

I suggest starting with an empty _vsvimrc and adding a line at a time to find where the error is.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the problem was in my _vsvimrc file. When I wrote my question here I didn't know that VsVim actually reloaded the file and all shortcuts are working, except that it printed that message. VsVim could use some more diagnostic functionalists. e.g. when I try to look on all the mappings I have, it shows them but only the first screen and I'm not able to scroll down... Besides that AWSOME!!! :)